# How to store user data in struct array in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm writing a contract to store student data in array. As we can not store different datatypes in one array so I used struct array. And I made a setter function to store data in array. But when I call this setter function an error occurs. I think it's because I'm trying to store large data and it exceed some limits (may be). So please help me to remove this error or suggest an alternative.

That is my input to setter function:

```
"Husnain","Islamabad","0307-6557305",434,"27-10-1997",8,3,"UET"
```

Thank you

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract studentRecord
{
    address owner;

    constructor()
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct student
    {
        string Name;
        string Address;
        string Phone_Num;
        uint16 Roll_Num;
        string DOB;
        uint8 Sem;
        uint8 CGPA;
        string Uni_Name;
    }

    student[] public StudentRecord;

    function setStudentRecords(string calldata _name, string calldata _address, string calldata _phoneNumber, uint16 _rollNumber,
                              string calldata _DOB, uint8 _sem, uint8 _CGPA, string calldata _UniName) public
    {
        uint len = StudentRecord.length;
        StudentRecord[len].Name = _name;
        StudentRecord[len].Address = _address;
        StudentRecord[len].Phone_Num = _phoneNumber;
        StudentRecord[len].Roll_Num = _rollNumber;
        StudentRecord[len].DOB = _DOB;
        StudentRecord[len].Sem = _sem;
        StudentRecord[len].CGPA = _CGPA;
        StudentRecord[len].Uni_Name = _UniName;
    }

    function GetStudentRecord(uint index) public view returns(student memory)
    {
        return StudentRecord[index];
    }

    function studentCount() public view returns(uint)
    {
        return StudentRecord.length;
    }
}
```

[The error image is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnqHa.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign to index of the `StudentRecord` that is out of bounds.

Example: The array is empty, so `StudentRecord.length` is 0. But the index 0 does not exist yet, so you can't write to it.

**Solution:** Use `.push()` member of the array to resize it and store new item.

```
function setStudentRecords(string calldata _name, string calldata _address, string calldata _phoneNumber, uint16 _rollNumber,
                              string calldata _DOB, uint8 _sem, uint8 _CGPA, string calldata _UniName) public
{
    StudentRecord.push(  // resize the array and store new item
        student(         // of type `student`
            _name,
            _address,
            _phoneNumber,
            _rollNumber,
            _DOB,
            _sem,
            _CGPA,
            _UniName
        )
    );
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#array-members

Comment: Thank you Sir It worked whooo it really worked. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: @MHusnainAbbas  Consider to accept this answer to help other users